# Why is SimpleXYSeries not suitable for dynamic data, and how to implement a "dynamic data" XYSeries class?

Tags: java, androidplot

In the AndroidPlot tutorial on [dynamic sensor plots](http://androidplot.com/docs/dynamically-plotting-sensor-data/), it says:

> ...if you care about about minimizing resource usage then you should implement XYSeries instead. SimpleXYPlot was meant for use in plots that are static or comprised of a small number of samples that change infrequently.

And in the source [SimpleXYSeries.java](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/397fac6a3541b4020a716e958a9c0b42bd2450fd/AndroidPlot-Core/src/main/java/com/androidplot/xy/SimpleXYSeries.java?at=master#cl-63)

> This is a convenience class and should only be used for static data models; it is not suitable for representing dynamically changing data.

My question is two-fold:

1. What is it about SimpleXYSeries that makes it not suitable for
   displaying dynamic data?
2. Any guidance or top-level overview of how to write my own "dynamic-ready" implementation of the XYSeries interface?

**EDIT:**

Following the [example here](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/8ceb1bc8a5dc47f7b65ada0304b1bf8583312161/Examples/DemoApp/src/com/androidplot/demos/OrientationSensorExampleActivity.java?at=master#cl-222), I'm currently calling removeFirst() and addLast() on the SimpleXYSeries to update my data before calling redraw(). Looking through the source, it seems SimpleXYSeries is storing its datapoints in LinkedLists which is completely understandable. However, I still don't quite understand the performance snag here.

Answer (score 1):

To make dynamic data you have to make a new SimpleXYSeries every time the data changes.  Lots of memory allocation and copying goes on.  If you implement the interface directly you can organise to have no memory allocation and no copying of the data.

The best method for your own interface really depends upon where the dynamic data is coming from and how it is being updated.  You just need to provide the methods to return the right data from your own storage of it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've clarified my question as I'm still not quite sure what you mean by "make a new SimpleXYSeries every time the data changes". Calling removeFirst() and addLast() simply updates the underlying LinkedList, and does not copy all the data, right?